# cgps : GPS timeout

Tags: gps

I use neo 6 ublox 6 GPS module. I choose to connect the GPS to the raspberry using a USB port. I followed these steps:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0  
$GPRMC,144034.00,V,,,,,,,090315,,,N*75
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,144034.00,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*60
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
$GPGSV,1,1,01,15,,,25*7B

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd   
start gpsd automatically: yes
Should gpsd handle attached USB receivers automatically: yes
Device the GPS receiver is attached to: <leave blank>
Options to gpsd: -n /dev/ttyUSB0
gpsd control socket path: <use default>

sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
cgps -s
**NO FIX**
```

What should I do for NO FIX problem?

Comment: if you run cgps (without -s) do you get any data? If you only have a few satellites I think it reports NO FIX. Also use gpspipe.

Comment: Does your GPS have a clear view of the sky?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yes, I have a clear sky view. window ledge

Comment: @rob unfortunately i got no data when i tried cgps

Comment: cgps and gpspipe should both just show curated data in the same way as your cat command did. Only things I can suggest are update, reboot and try a powered USB hub.

Comment: A window ledge is not a clear sky view. the house is blocking it for approx 180 degrees. Try it out in the yard away from buildings and trees.

Comment: The cat command showed no fix data. Your problem has nothing to do with cgps.  Sometimes you have to wait for the GPS to figure out what satellites are in view by loading the almanac. Called a"cold start ".

Answer (score 5):

my GPS module is based on L80-39 chip, I've installed gpsd and gpsd-clients packages to drive this module, and reboot my Raspberry Pi.
you can try those command as following:

```
sudo killall gpsd
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.socket
```

or Edit /etc/default/gpsd file, input your device name and parameters:

[image]

```
sudo systemctl enable gpsd.socket
sudo systemctl start gpsd.socket 
sudo cgps -s
```

it may works. good luck.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was only solvable by altering parameters in '/etc/default/gpsd'
there you can set your /dev/ttyUSB0 for example and -n if the normal method does not work

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/default/gpsd` and add your serial port in `DEVICES`, like

```
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
```